# How can I export SMS opt outs from Mobile Connect?

Tags: mobileconnect

I believe I should be able to export SMS opt outs from MobileConnect using a Query in Email. But I can't work it out.

I simply want to have an automated daily export of our SMS opt outs to our ftp.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to create a query... "SELECT
  _MobileSubscriptionID AS MobileSubscriptionID,
  _SubscriptionDefinitionID AS SubscriptionDefinitionID,
  _MobileNumber AS MobileNumber,
  _OptOutStatusID AS OptOutStatusID,
  _OptOutMethodID AS OptOutMethodID,
  _OptOutDate AS OptOutDate,
  _OptInStatusID AS OptInStatusID,
  _OptInMethodID AS OptInMethodID,
  _OptInDate AS OptInDate
FROM _MobileSubscription" to a DE with the same fields name (as text) but it doesn't work. Any guidence would be appreciated.